# Why python metaclass is not working in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

```py
class My_meta(type):

    def hello(cls):
        print("hey")

class Just_a_class(metaclass=My_meta):
    pass

a = Just_a_class()
a.hello()
```

Above code is giving:

> AttributeError: 'Just_a_class' object has no attribute 'hello'

Please suggest the changes to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: A metaclass is not the same as a superclass. Instances don't inherit methods from a metaclass.

Comment: Why do you believe that an instance of `Just_a_class` will have that method?

Answer (score 1):

Methods in a metaclass are inherited by the class object, not class instances. You can call the function this way:

```
Just_a_class.hello()
// or
a = Just_a_class()
a.__class__.hello()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!